# ngFor in a tr not working as expected in angular2

Tags: angular

I'm playing around with angular 2 (first day;)).

I'm using a component that displays a tr, and the another that will repeat tr's inside of it.

```
<h3>Sensor list</h3>
<a (click)="refreshSensors()" class="btn btn-primary">Escanear Sensores</a>

<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Sensor</th>
            <th>Description</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <sensor-list [sensors]="sensors"></sensor-list>
</table>
```

and then, in sensor list:

```
<h3>Sensor list</h3>
<a (click)="refreshSensors()" class="btn btn-primary">Escanear Sensores</a>

<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Sensor</th>
            <th>Description</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <sensor-list [sensors]="sensors"></sensor-list>
</table>
```

While ngFor is repeating the tr's propertly, i'm getting a  tag inside my html that makes the table not displaying as it should:

[image: td's not displaying as expected]

```
    <table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Sensor</th>
            <th>Description</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <sensor-list><tbody><!--template bindings={}--><tr>
    <td>R2D2</td>
    <td>Description of r2d2</td>
</tr><tr>
    <td>C3PO</td>
    <td>Description of c3po</td>
</tr></tbody></sensor-list>
</table>
```

Do I have to specify the tag i want to display in the component? what is the correct way of doing this in angular?

Comment: I don't see your ngFor usage in your code.

Comment: Its not clear what you are trying to say...

Comment: I think that the template of `sensor list` isn't the right one ;-)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Angular 2 always leaves the host tag in the DOM and only inserts the HTML from your template into this host tag. Since a list of `tr` tags isn't really a good use for a component, I would rethink your code design choice there. It would probably be better to put the whole table into a component.

Comment: Yeah, just I've just realised about that after asking and rethinking the question, the component should be the whole table. Thanks very much @ rinukkusu

Answer (score 3):

### Components inside HTML table

I want to expand on that a little bit more. This is tricky one. Probably most of the people starting with dynamically rendered tables encountered that.

Here is the code you've got (cleaned):

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'table-body',
  template: `
    <tr>
      <td>Cell 1</td>
      <td>Cell 2</td>
    </tr>
  `
})
class TableBodyComponent {}

@Component({
  selector: 'sg-app',
  template: `
    <table>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Header 1</th>
          <th>Header 2</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <table-body></table-body>
    </table>
  `,
  directives: [TableBodyComponent]
})
export class AppComponent {}
```

What Angular renders is the following: 
[image: Angular 2 Table Rendering]

And it's not a valid HTML (ref: [MDN Table](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/table)). This way view is broken and unpredictable.

### Components on table rows

However you still can add components or directives (as an attribute) to the `<tr>` tag:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: '[table-row]',
  template: `
    <td>Cell 1</td>
    <td>Cell 2</td>
  `
})
class TableBodyComponent {}

@Component({
  selector: 'sg-app',
  template: `
    <table>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Header 1</th>
          <th>Header 2</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
         <tr table-row></tr>      
      </tbody>
    </table>
  `,
  directives: [TableBodyComponent]
})
export class AppComponent {}
```

This way you can also add `*ngFor` to the `<tr>`

Comment: mmm I didn't know aboyt the '[selector]' thing. As I said, this is my first day ;)

Comment: `selector` is generally an css selector so you can put here specific types of elements or classes or attribute types etc. It's cool but for components is recommended to use just a tag name.

Comment: This is great. Saved me a lot of time. And it's obvious: angular produces html that is not valid.

Comment: Not working in Angular 7+. Can't use selectors that aren't a element :/

Answer (score 0):

Your sensor-list component should be like this

Is your sensor component like this

```
import {Component, Input} from 'angular2/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'sensor-list',
  template: `
       <tbody>
          <tr *ngFor="let row of sensors">
            <td>{{row.sensor}}</td>
            <td>{{row.description}}</td>
          </tr>
       <tbody>
  `,
  providers: []
})
export class Sensor {
  @Input('sensors') type: any;

  constructor() {}
}
```

And your home component's template should be like this :

```
<sensor-list [sensors]="sensors"></sensor-list>
```

Comment: Thanks, I ended up with something similar, but with the whole table, not just the tbody

Answer (score 0):

Do something alike

PARENT COMPONENT TEMPLATE

```
<tr tool *ngFor='let tool of tools' [_tool]='tool'>
```

CHILD COMPONENT

```
import {Component, Input, OnChanges} from '@angular/core'
import {ITool} from '../../app/common/interfaces/ITool'

@Component({
    selector: '[tool]',
    templateUrl: 'app/toolslist/tool.template.html',
    styleUrls: ['app/toolslist/tool.style.css'],
})

export class ToolComponent implements OnChanges{
    @Input() _tool: ITool; 

    constructor() {

    }

    ngOnChanges():void{
        console.log(this._tool);
    };
}
```